# Set Default Value for input type month

Tags: php, html

Is it possible for me to set the value of `input = 'month'`using php? I have seen that it is possible using javascript.. but I want to achieve it using php....

I'm trying to set a default value for the `input = month`..
however the value that I set doesn't take effect..

here's what I did.

when I tried to display it outside the element `<?=date('F-Y')?>` it displays the date and month just fine..

```
 <input type="month" value="<?=date('F-Y')?>"  class="form-control per_date_inputs"  name="month"/>
```

Comment: Check the source code. There might be some problem with quotes. Also if possible attach rendered output to help us understand better :)

Comment: That should work fine, did you try to check html output ? If you see your output correct, you should check the running javascript on your page.

Comment: @georoot I have tried inspect element.. and I can see the `value = March 2016` but it doesn't appear in my ui...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<input type="month" value="<?=date('Y-m')?>"  class="form-control per_date_inputs"  name="month"/>
```

Comment: You need to supply the date like this: 2016-03

Comment: lol... maybe the `month` type doesn't recognize the `March` because it is expecting a digit...

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
<input type="month" value="<?=date('F-Y')?>"  class="form-control per_date_inputs"  name="month"/>
```

Use this

```
<input type="month" value="<?=date('Y-m')?>"  class="form-control per_date_inputs"  name="month"/>
<input type="month" value="2016-03"  class="form-control per_date_inputs"  name="month"/>
```

input type=month takes "yyyy-mm" format only

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna to make a code for default value for Date or Month; here is the solution:

- This is for Date:

  ```html
  <input type="date" name="" id="" value="1982-10-25">
  ```

  Write the year first then, the month then, the day.
- This is for Month:

  ```html
  <input type="month" name="" id="" value="1982-10">
  ```

  Write the year first then, the month.